# Is there any option to install packages in a tree structure like how the node versions below 0.12 use to do

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to upgrade my workspace from node 0.12.7 to v10.13.0. With this I am encountering an issue wherein the previous npm install used to create a tree like structure of the dependencies, ie. if A->B->C
it used to create a dependency structure like
A
   B
      C
Now the latest versions install dependencies in the following way
A
    B
    C

Comment: Your application should not be aware of the node_modules structure as it should all be abstracted by the import system.  What is the underlying issue you are facing?

Comment: @twinlakes .If lets say i had a package.json in A and that installed B. I was supposed to create a tgz file of B that would inturn contain C. So most of my old code was dependant on this idea. Now that with the new npm, when I run npm install on A it creates both B and C as siblings in its node_modules, so I cant have this current functionality. I  am just trying to maintain this functaionality.